# Do events very far away happen in a different timeline?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, observers, causality

*I am not sure how to ask this question in a concise manner so I am sure somebody out there explained it but I cannot seem to find it.*

So I recently watched some videos explaining that $c$ not only represents the speed of light but the speed of cause and effect. That got me wondering, if a star is a million light years away, we clearly are seeing how it was a million years ago. But what I do not get is the cause and effect portion. Is the star a million years ahead of our time because for any event to propogate, it has to take at least a million years? If the speed of cause and effect or in other words, the speed of time (time is just cause and effect) is finite, would that make events that happen there in the past or future? Moreover, is the definition of now relative to the observer?

Comment: it basically means that the galaxy today cannot affect you, it can only do that in a million years. Right now only what happened 1 million years ago in that star can affect you (let us say they sent a killer ray a million years ago that is getting here just now).  So you do not have access to what is happening NOW anywhere other than at where you are right now.

Comment: The best way to understand it is the idea of light cones (you can look up the visuals).

Comment: @VJZ Cause and effect part means that if this star exploded into supernova NOW, our telescopes will see it only after 1 million years. So Earth/Sun/Our Galaxy and this star is causally disconnected by 1 million years duration. And none of our galaxy events which are happening now, can be the cause or effect of some event which is happening now at this star system. Unless 1 million years has passed, and then it can be related somehow.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rietdijk%E2%80%93Putnam_argument

Comment: What do you mean by "in a different timeline"?

Answer (score 1):

To begin, c is not the speed of all cause and effect but the maximum speed at which causes can propagate. If your doorbell rings, the resulting vibrations in the air travel at the speed of sound to affect your eardrum, not at the speed of light.

The idea of 'now' is not as meaningful in SR as it was in the Newtonian picture of reality. If you talk about a distant event happening 'now', what you mean is that it has the same time coordinate, in your frame of reference, as your local 'now'. However, in any other frame moving relative to yours it will have different time coordinate to your local 'now', so there is no agreement whatsoever about which distant events are actually happening 'now' because there is no common distant 'now'.

You might find it helpful to contemplate what now means on Earth from the perspective of three extremely distant observers standing together in some galaxy stationary relative to Earth. Since they are stationary relative to you, according to SR you and they share a common time axis, so that 'now' for them has the same time coordinate as 'now' for you. However, if one of the three people starts to walk towards the Earth, while the other walks away, they are no longer stationary relative to you, so 'now' on Earth for one of them could could be a day last week, while for the other it could be a day next week. For you on Earth, now is still now, but each of the three distant observers would assign a different time coordinate to it.

Answer (score 0):

Any event happening on a star that is a million of light years away happens in real time. That is,if something is happening there, it is occuring as you're thinking of it right now. It's just that we can't possibly know anything about it in real time. Because, for a signal to reach here (which can only travel with maximum speed c, the speed light), it would take a million years.

What you see are the signal carrying data regarding a very old event that occured on the star a million year ago. That data is very old as it has travelled a million years, ending up being observed by you. It is meaningless to say that the star right now is in "future" or "million year ahead of us". Rather, it is more like what you observe is a very old data about it. So it would be more correct to say that "current state of star is how it would be million years after the old data we observe at any moment."(which is impossible for us to know).

> Is the star a million years ahead of our time because for any event to propogate, it has to take at least a million years?

If you're referring to the "state of the star", then no, it is not million year ahead of us. Just that you'll get to know what state it was in when you were thinking about it, only after million years.  But after these million years, the star would've already went through a lot in real time.

> If the speed of cause and effect or in other words, the speed of time (time is just cause and effect) is finite, would that make events that happen there in the past or future?

"Speed of time" is very confusing term. Time doesn't have a speed. Time in itself is a measure of relative change in configuration. If there's no relative change in configuration/state, it becomes impossible to measure time ( even then time exists though). Thus time is measurment of relative change (change involve cause and effect).  Speed is change per unit time. It should be said that speed of relative change in configuration, is limited, as observed by a human. Coming to your question, No, the event that "happen there" are niether of past or furture. Everything happen in real time in the universe, wihtout you being aware of it due to the limits of your perception.

> Moreover, is the definition of now relative to the observer?

You can take "Now" as an immidiate, possibly observable relative change of state in process, anywhere within a system or environment. So, "now" is relative to the change and it's observation. "Now" at a universal level is an unquantifiable state of the system. Time is measurement of the change. So after a cetain amount of time, the state would be different. This difference is the change. Change exists by virtue of cause and effect.